While trying to create wallet and gateway connection profile for hyperledger fabric, Getting WEFT warnings
Getting Weft Warning error while trying to run this code: "curl -s http://console.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080/ak/api/v1/components | weft microfab -w ./_wallets -p ./_gateways -m ./_msp -f"


$:  % curl -s http://console.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080/ak/api/v1/components | weft microfab -w ./_wallets -p ./_gateways -m ./_msp -f
WEFT WARNING: skipping argument microfab
WEFT WARNING: skipping argument ./_wallets
WEFT WARNING: skipping argument ./_gateways
WEFT WARNING: skipping argument -m
WEFT WARNING: skipping argument ./_msp
WEFT ERROR 1: No file name specified!
WEFT WILL NOW EXIT...
Usage: Weft [args]
  -b: specify the CTA id to simulate (default 0x0x0)
      can be an integer or an x-separated tuple e.g. 0x0x1 or 1x2
  -d: print detailed information for error reporting
      this includes line numbers for blocked threads under deadlock and
      and per-thread and per-address information for races
  -f: specify the input file
  -g: specify the grid dimensions for the kernel being simulated
      can be an integer or an x-separated tuple e.g. 32x32x2 or 32x1
      Weft will still only simulate a single CTA specified by '-b'
  -i: instrument execution
  -n: number of threads per CTA
      can be an integer or an x-separated tuple e.g. 64x2 or 32x8x1
  -p: print individual Weft thread files (one file per thread!)




It looks like whatever weft command you have installed is not the one you are expecting. It should this (globally installed) NPM package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hyperledger-labs/weft
Make sure that is installed and ahead of your other weft command in your shell's PATH. Or you could explicitly provide the path to the correct weft command on the command-line to avoid changing your shell's PATH.

Thanks for this input. I had installed a wrong one.
